# PG::NumericValueOutOfRange for column string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting this error although the column is a string. This error comes when I output into my html

```
PG::NumericValueOutOfRange: ERROR:  value "10152858807121189" is out of range for type integer
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1
```

My application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

  helper_method :current_user
end
```

Migration file:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :provider
      t.string :uid
      t.string :name
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :image_url
      t.string :email
      t.string :access_token
      t.string :access_secret
      t.string :refresh_token
      t.string :expires_at

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Try adding `self.primary_key = :uid` in your model if you are using Rails 3.2 and up. If you are using a previous version: `set_primary_key :uid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primary key column called **id** is added implicitly, as it's the default primary key for all Active Record models, and, of course, it is **integer**. The **uid** column is string.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :provider
      t.integer :uid  *** uid must be integer
      t.string :name
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :image_url
      t.string :email
      t.string :access_token
      t.string :access_secret
      t.string :refresh_token
      t.string :expires_at

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```